# Windows 8 Store App and jQuery - MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, windows-8

I am writing a Windows 8 JavaScript Store App (using Cordova). When I use jQuery with Windows 8, why is it I have to modify the jQuery library to use the following for a few of the functions?

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction
```

Preferably I would prefer not to do this as it is a slight inconvenience whenever a new version of jQuery Mobile is release (which, thankfully, is not often) - is there a setting in the project to disable this?

I am using jQuery v1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile v1.3.2 (which are the latest stable releases). I read this is fixed as of jQuery 2.x - can someone confirm whether this is true?

If so, is it unsafe to use jQuery 2.x in my mobile app project? Are there functions in jQuery v1.9.1 which jQuery Mobile v1.3.2 rely on, which are unavailable in jQuery v2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction for certain functions because jQuery adds HTML in an, for Microsoft, unsafe way. Some HTML elements and attributes are considered unsafe and the App crashes when jQuery unsafely adds them to the DOM, using for instance append or innerHTML. The unsafe HTML elements and attributes can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465388.aspx).

This problem is as I know not fixed in jQuery 2.x. I'm still struggling to get the async page changes with unsafe keywords to work. I'll let you know when I have a workaround or fix.

**Update**: MSOpenTech created a JavaScript dynamic content shim which solves this problem. Take a look at my [blog post](http://dibranmulder.blogspot.nl/2015/02/combo-breaker-reloaded.html) or at their [Github page](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat).

Comment: Thanks! Great answer - it's pretty annoying. I hope the guys at jQuery to fix it soon. Let me know if/when you have found something - that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check my latest [blogpost](http://dibranmulder.blogspot.nl/2014/03/combo-breaker-cordova-jqm-windows8.html) for some workarounds and quirks I found for JQM in combination with Windows 8.

Comment: I updated my answer with some information about the "JavaScript dynamic content shim" created by MSOpenTech.

Answer (score 4):

Call this function in deviceready event and alert and jQuery html method will work everywhere

```
function WinAppHack() {

    if (MSApp && MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction) {

        // override jquery html method
        var old_html = $.fn.html;
        $.fn.html = function () {
            var args = arguments;
            var This = this;
            var result = null;
            //$(this).css('font-size', 24)
            MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
                result = old_html.apply(This, args);
            });
            return result;
        };

        // override alert method
        alert = function (msg, Closed) {
            if (!Closed)
                Closed = function () { };
            navigator.notification.alert(
            msg,  
            Closed,         
            'Message',       
            'OK'                
            );
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the append(), prepend(), appendTo(), prependTo() methods? html() is not the only method to manipulate the DOM, sorry. Anyway I vote up your post because this issue is driving me mad, I'm about to drop my WP8 app and focus in Android alone.